# Pandas - TimeSeries to Monthly series plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple timeseries of daily observations over 2 years.  I basically want to plot the daily date for each month of the series (looking daily seasonality that occurs each month).    For example:

[image]

I'd expect a series on the chart for each month.   Is there a way to split the dataframe easily to do this?

I'm trying to avoid doing this for each month/year...

```
df['JUN-2016'] = data[df['date'].month==12 & df['date'].year==2016]
```

A sample of the dataframe:

```
DATE    
2015-01-05  2.7483
2015-01-06  2.7400
2015-01-07  2.7250
2015-01-08  2.7350
2015-01-09  2.7350
2015-01-12  2.7350
2015-01-13  2.7450
2015-01-14  2.7450
2015-01-15  2.7350
2015-01-16  2.7183
2015-01-19  2.7300
2015-01-20  2.7150
2015-01-21  2.7150
2015-01-22  2.6550
2015-01-23  2.6500
2015-01-27  2.6450
2015-01-28  2.6350
2015-01-29  2.6100
2015-01-30  2.5600
2015-02-02  2.4783
2015-02-03  2.4700
```

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] ?

Comment: It seemed kind of silly adding a bunch of code to make a fake time series....

Comment: I do not know how someone can help without you creative a MCVE :(( ! The reason I asked is because, without me or anyone else coming up with their own data and answering the question, it is always better to ask for OP's data . -_-

Comment: Still not really sure what you're after...  you want me to paste a dataframe into the question?

Comment: Not the entire dataframe, just a [small example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/9609447) of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert the column with all dates in your dataframe (let's say it is called `df["dates"]`) into datetimeformat:

```
df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

also you need to import datetime library:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Then you can just do:

```
startDateOfInterval = "2016-05-31"
endDateOfInterval = "2016-07-01"

dfOfDesiredMonth = df[df["date"].apply(lambda x: x > datetime.strptime(startDateOfInterval, "%Y-%m-%d") and x < datetime.strptime(endDateOfInterval, "%Y-%m-%d"))]
```

The `df` you will get will then only contain the rows with date within this interval.